# Xcode to run watch extension successfully

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, watchos-2

I am using xCode 7, running on ios 9.0.2 and apple watch os 2. When I try to run my watch app, it always show like this forever.

[image]

I have done like this to run successfully from xCode.

1) I have deleted app and install.
2) I unpair and pair again. 
3) I reset content and setting in watch.

It is still not okay. How shall I do? It so freak me out.

Comment: Probably there is something wrong in the new xCode ... I have a similar issue but in my case xCode is very slow to run the app on a real watch and sometime it fails with strange errors

Comment: Have you shut your watch off and on?  Sometime, after a few hours of using Xcode, the watch app is installed onto my watch, but won't start automatically.  Turning the watch off usually fixes it.

Comment: I have tried to turn off/ reset watch. Sometimes, it is okay but it always happen again.

Answer (score 0):

At first of all, You are not alone. WatchOS2 SDK not works smoothly for everyone. It looks like to debugging experience of widgets when they are introduced first time.

There is no way to make it work always, however you can increase the success rate of attaching debugger. (Yes, it sounds silly)

1. Connect your Apple Watch to your Mac that running Xcode using recharging cable. That usb cable is not just recharging cable, it can transfer data also, Using cable provides much more fast and successful debug. Remember that debugging with air connection seems to almost impossible.
2. Open Device Manager(Window > Devices) and choose your iPhone. Now you can see small triangle at left bottom, click it. Then you can see real time log of Apple Watch. Even attaching debug was failed, you can still see any log message that you made with `NSLog` here.
3. It takes pretty long time to attach debugger since the bug of the watchOS2 that is [failure of launching app first time](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17677). Keep eyes on device log, You can see the launch failed log and watch os trying to kill it, after first kill, device log will say "Ready to debug", If you saw this message Xcode will attach in short time after.
4. What if the there is no "ready to debug" message and your app is killed by watchOS, then just launch your app from your Apple Watch again, not by Xcode.